# Conflict between python-slugify and awesome-slugify

Tags: python, django, pip, slugify

I am using the `awesome-slugify` python library (1.6.5) but for another Django app I need also to use the `csvkit` python library (version 1.0.3). Once I install the `csvkit` (`pip install csvkit`), I start getting an error when importing the Slugify.

I figured out, that this is cause `csvkit` also required the `python-slugify` (2.0.1) in order to work.

There is a conflict between `awesome-slugify` and `python-slugify`.

In the past I have used all 3 together without any issue. The versions I have used were the following:

1. `python-slugify: 1.2.4`
2. `csvkit: 1.0.0`
3. `awesome-slugify: 1.6.2`

I thought I could solve the issue by doing:

1. `pip install csvkit==1.0.0 <-- this still installs the latest python-slugify`
2. `pip install python-slugify==1.2.4`
3. `pip install awesome-slugify==1.6.2`

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work because somehow the two slugify libraries share the same folders. The problem is that `python-slugify` is installed as a dependency of the `csvkit`. So it's not straightforward to me, how I could define the folder name of the installation inside the site-packages..

What a mess..

Answer (score 1):

Both [python-slugify](https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify/tree/master/slugify) and [awesome-slugify](https://github.com/voronind/awesome-slugify/tree/master/slugify) use the same top-level directory `slugify`. There is no way to install both at the same time. And there is no way to change the directory because `import slugify` (in `csvkit`, for example) requires the directory to be named exactly `slugify`.